# Angular2 model-driven forms and prepopulated values

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have an app that I built for rc.1 that I'm now upgrading to rc.3, and the new forms module. I've been ripping my hair out beacuse of it, and decided to see if anyone had any ideas what I'm doing wrong.

Basically I'm building the form like this (fb is an instance of FormBuilder):

```
this.form = fb.group({
  client_id: ['Customer', Validators.compose([Validators.required, formValidators.mustBeNumber])],
  data_owner_id: ['Data Owner (if different from Customer)', formValidators.mustBeNumber],
  order_time: [new Date(), Validators.compose([formValidators.mustBeDate, Validators.required])]
})
```

And prepopulating with ngModel like this:

```
<form class="form"  [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitJob(f)">
      <legend>{{title}}</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="client_id">Client</label>
   <select (change)="clientHasChanged($event.target.value)" class="form-control" id="client_id" formControlName="client_id" [(ngModel)]='job.client_id'>
              <option value="" disabled selected>Customer</option>
              <option *ngFor="let client of clients" [ngValue]="client.client_id">{{client.client_id}} - {{client.client_id_name}}</option>
            </select>
```

This worked perfectly fine for rc.1 (outside of the renamed directives), but now I'm getting an error:

> browser_adapter.ts:74 EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:4200/app/+wih2/+job/job.component.html:6:129
>   ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No value accessor for ''

Removing the ngModel removes the error, but I kinda need the data it provides, and I don't know of any other way to resolve this.

I'm using the new forms module, and yes I am bootstrapping with it:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms(), HTTP_PROVIDERS, APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

Looking forward to some answers!

Edit:
Full stacktrace [image: stacktrace]

Comment: can you post all your error ?

Comment: but my guess is you forgot to put `import {NgForm }    from '@angular/common';` And you actually don't need to rely on ngModel. You can subscribe to client_id

Comment: I am importing NgForm. I'll post the entire stacktrace tomorrow morning.

Comment: Added the full stacktrace to original post

Comment: That is one confusing error message. Sorry, I don't have any good answer now. Maybe the problem is not in the code you shown here. If you really wanna figure out, build a plunker example to repeat it.

Comment: Figured it out with the help of kara @ angular team - I was using NgModel from @angular/common, but had to be from @angular/forms. Didnt think it was coupled directly with forms >_>

Answer (score 1):

I think the better solution is using Reactive solution.

something like this in your ngOnInit()

```
this.form.controls["client_id"].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    this.job.client_id = value;
});
```

And use property binding in template

Comment: I don't see how this would help? I'm getting data from a rest api, where it will prepopulate those values if they exist. The function i use in (change) works fine I believe.

Comment: Ah... it is a way you don't need to use ngModel, because you are actually using Reactive Form.

Comment: I can see how I could use this in a reversed manner though. Get the data from the api, and add the values to the form from there. That could possibly work. I'll look into it in the morning! Now sleep. :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that I imported NgModel from @angular/common, instead of @angular/forms - I wasn't aware that NgModel was coupled so tightly with forms.